# Message: element not interactable. Xpath correct

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

How can I click? Obviously with the mouse I can, and a new mask appears. While with the click () the following error appears.

Obviously the Xpath is correct in fact it reports the following code =

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='example']")
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9e25c2b4350ca89b8da611a6dc63ae0c", element="f8dc7d1a-a31a-4fc8-98ec-34ff5a7fa12e")>
```

this message error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='example']"))).click()
```

you need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: After I try, but the element is visible. In fact I use the debug console. I'm afraid it's an interaction problem

Comment: @lolino : Are you getting the same error while using above code?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>    

raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

:(

Comment: @lolino : It seems element is not visible on the page. Can you post the html or share url if i can see any parent having hidden style.